# Simultaneous request to a get form with laravel with diferent parameters has the same response

Tags: laravel

I got a problem with my Laravel 7 app (Front and Back), where i have a form with the GET method, but i have a problem when i have two persons at the same time doing the request, if they press the button at the same time, both are going to have the same result even though they have different parameters. How can i fix this problem ? I was thinking in make some request for ip, so the server can't send the same response to both.

Do you know what can i do to prevent this problem for 2 or more simultaneous request ?

EDIT 1: I have made some changes, for example I made a table in the database with the ip and the interactions, so the system can not return the same for two different ip.

Thank u

Comment: So separately requests work properly?

Comment: If I make two request no at the same time, it works perfect

Comment: It is possible view cache the same for two requests, so laravel make it single, and answer for both requests. For testing, please ad `CACHE_EXPIRE=-1` to your server `.env` file

Comment: The app doesn't work with login, it's a GET method form to search places in a list. For example I made the form with my computer and with my cellphone and if i do this at the same time, the response is the same, but only when is at the same time. I don't know if the query it's not optimized so give the client the same response for both.

Comment: in what way is this action dependent upon time?

Comment: it doesn't depends of the time, but if i have two clients at the same time doing the request, one of the clients is not going to get the desired response